# Web/Mobile Analytics - identified/anonymous users

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

We implemented Web/Mobile analytics and we aren't seeing any anonymous sessions populate in the data being collected. See support case 133655 for more info. Millions of sessions, and the tool says 100% are identified, but only a very small fraction are actually identified/targetable within the product, and it's showing 0 as anonymous. The numbers are not adding up to the total session count.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?